# What services exist for checking a website loading time?

Tags: webapp-rec

I know of YSlow with Firefox and http://webwait.com/ .

Any other services around?

Comment: How is this not constructive? Not to mention that Jeff answered it himself.

Comment: It's an app recommendation request. Please see our [help/on-topic].

Comment: Technically it's also a duplicate - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6496/web-app-to-test-web-page-speed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google's Page Speed

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

AOL's WebPageTest

http://www.webpagetest.org/

GTMetrix

http://gtmetrix.com/‎

Comment: yes, webpagetest.org is pretty neat, indeed.

Comment: some tips for speeding up static file download in an asp.net website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555304/tips-for-serving-static-files-faster-like-javascripts-css-and-images

Answer (score 0):

Google-Chrome and Opera have builtin tools to analyze websites, including loadtime.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to YSlow and WebPageTest mentioned in other answers I use the LORI (life of request information) extension for Firefox during development to give a quick indication of page speed.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1743/

It adds a few fields to the status bar to give you a quick overview of some important figures: time to first byte, time to completion, total size, number of requests

[LORI status bar http://cl.ly/1XHi/content](http://cl.ly/1XHi/content)

Answer (score 0):

1. Pingdom Tools Full Page Test: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt

Comment: Would have posted more, but don't have enough juju on my account.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is another nice one I found](http://whichloadsfaster.com/).